# Least area of the image of a simply connected domain under holomorphic maps

Tags: complex-analysis

I found the following statement in the book "The Kernel Function and Conformal mapping" at page 23-24 by Stefan Bergman:

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded, simply connected domain in $\mathbb{C}.$ Let $p\in\Omega.$ Now consider the family $\mathcal{F}:=\{f\in\mathcal{O}(\Omega,\mathbb{C}):f(p)=0,\,f'(p)=1\}$. Given $f\in\mathcal{F}$ let $D_f$ denote the range of $f.$ Then $D_f$ has least area in the case in which $D_f$ is a disc with center at the origin.

I'm not able to see why this is true. Please help to understand the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let's be clear about what exactly Bergman claims.

[image: Google Book snippet]

> It is well known<sup>2</sup> that the minimum area is attained in the case in which $D$ is a circle with center at the origin.

Explanation: Bergman considers the range to be a Riemann surface, which can be multi-sheeted over the plane. In plain/plane terms, he counts the area of the range with multiplicities: a part covered twice counts twice, etc. The area of range with multiplicities is  the integral of Jacobian determinant over the domain -- this can be taken as definition.

As Daniel Fischer pointed out to me, we can assume that the domain is itself a disk centered at $0$ by pre-composing $f$ with  a  Riemann map. I will normalize the Riemann map so that its derivative at $0$ is $1$; thus, the disk is not necessarily of unit radius. Let $R$ be its radius.

So, now we have $f:\{z: |z|<R\}\to D_f$ with $f'(0)=1$. 
Write $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$. The derivative is $f'(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nz^{n-1}$. Viewed as a map on $\mathbb R^2$, $f$ has the Jacobian determinant $|f'(z)|^2$. The area of $D_f$ is the integral of Jacobian over $\{|z|<R\}$. Note that
$$|f'(z)|^2=f'(z)\overline{f'(z)}=
\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty mn a_m\overline{a_n}z^{m-1}  \bar z^{n-1}$$
Integrating in polar coordinates, we find that when $m\ne n$, the term $  z^{m-1} \bar  z^{n-1}$ integrates to zero over every circle, because it is a multiple of $e^{i(m-n)\theta}$. When $m=n$, the term is $n^2|a_n|^2|z|^{2n-2}$, which is nonnegative. Conclusion: the area iz minimized by setting all coefficients with $n>1$   to $0$.

For completemess, this is what you get after integration:
$$
\operatorname{area}(D_f)= \pi \sum_{n=1}^\infty  n |a_n|^2 R^{2n}  
$$

---

One may ask the same question without counting multiplicities: that is, minimize the area of   $D_f$ considered as a subset of $\mathbb C$.  The answer remains the same: the minimum is attained when $D_f$ is a disk. However, the proof I know is substantially more involved: it relies on the fact that capacity decreases under symmetrization. A story for another time...

Comment: There's a small problem in that the domain of $f$ is $\Omega$, not (necessarily) the unit disk. That can be treated by composing with a biholomorphic mapping $\varphi \colon \mathbb{D}\to \Omega$ with $\varphi(0) = p$ and $\varphi'(0) > 0$. There's another problem, which I don't see how to treat, namely that it is not given that $f$ is conformal, so how do we treat the case of a non-injective $f$? And does the conclusion even hold then?

Comment: @DanielFischer Actually, my answer (with your correction) still works for the claim that is actually made by Bergman (found on Google Books).

Comment: Yes. Counting sheets, the proof indeed remains simple. Nice job.

Comment: Got your idea, Thanks. But to understand I'll take time having also in my mind the concerns (above) that Daniel had. Thanks again.

Comment: I think the above answer is revised having the points that Daniel made?

Comment: @ Post no bills: One more concern:I thought that in the reference, the one Bergman mentioned(see your statement in rectangle), the statement in the rectangle is proved without using Riemann map, as if you go on reading the above para. he gives the formula for the function $f$ for which $D_f$ is a disc(minimum) area. And he does that using that $\Omega$ is a simply connected domain and the discussion done on pages 21-22. So I thought that if this is the case then actually we can prove Riemann mapping theorem in this way and also we know the biholomorphic map. Your thoughts please.

Comment: @Abelvikram (1) Yes, the answer was revised already. (2) Bergman does **not** prove the statement quoted at the beginning of my answer. He only points to reference [1] in the footnote. (3) What Bergman does prove on pages 21-22 is that the minimum of $\iint |f'|^2$ is attained by $f$ such that $f'(z)=K(z,\bar p)/K(p,\bar p)$. He then connects this to the known result that $f$ maps onto a disk to conclude that $\int K(z,\bar p)/K(p,\bar p)\,dz$ is a formula for the conformal map onto the disk.

Comment: @Abelvikram So,  we have a formula for biholomorphic map onto the disk, but it was proved using the knowledge that such a map exists (which I used in my answer). If you want to prove the Riemann mapping theorem in this way, you'll need another proof of the statement in my answer, without using the Riemann mapping theorem. Perhaps reference [1] in Bergman's book can help. I don't know what that reference is, as I don't have the book.

Comment: @Post no bills: Ok. Thanks. Yeah that;s what I was thinking. The reference is L Bieberbach, Lehbruch der Funktiontheorie, seems German :), anyway thanks for your time.

Comment: @Abelvikram If you are interested in building conformal maps (including the proof of Riemann mapping theorem) via the minimization of the Dirichlet integral, I recommend [Courant's book](http://books.google.com/books?id=FLr5JDljqY4C) which was recently republished by Dover.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look on the book.